# How to resolve confusing ANOVA results using type II sums of squares?

Tags: anova, sums-of-squares

Suppose we have the following data from the `R` package `afex`:

```
library(afex)
dd <- obk.long[obk.long$phase=='fup' & obk.long$hour=='1', c('id', 'treatment', 'gender', 'value')]
str(dd)
```

Basically, the dataset `dd` contains two between-individual factors `treatment` and `gender`:

```
 $ id       : Factor w/ 16 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ treatment: Factor w/ 3 levels "control","A",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ gender   : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ value    : num  2 4 7 4 4 9 8 6 5 8 ...
```

Performing a 2 x 2 ANOVA with type II sums of squares:

```
aov_car(value ~ treatment * gender + Error(id), data=dd, type=2)
```

yields the following results:

```
            Effect    df  MSE      F  ges p.value
1        treatment 2, 10 2.04 6.73 * .574    .014
2           gender 1, 10 2.04   1.83 .155    .205
3 treatment:gender 2, 10 2.04   1.35 .212    .304
```

However, the main effects of `treatment` and `gender` with type II sums of squares imply that they are assessed independently, without the inclusion of their interaction `treatment:gender`. This means that the following model:

```
aov_car(value ~ treatment + gender + Error(id), data=dd, type=2)
```

should provide the same results as the first model above. Surprisingly, it does not:

```
    Effect    df  MSE      F  ges p.value
1 treatment 2, 12 2.16 6.36 * .515    .013
2    gender 1, 12 2.16   1.73 .126    .212
```

What might I be missing conceptually? How to reconcile the two sets of MSEs and F-statistics arithmetically using their respective DFs?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the results are very close.

Then look at the degrees of freedom. Type II SS does not adjust for the interaction (you are correct) but the df are still adjusted for the inclusion of the interaction. That's why the denominator df is smaller in the first analysis than the second. The mean square error is divided by 10 or by 12.

Also, it looks like your sample size is only 16; this is probably too small for more than one factor. The usual rule of thumb is 10 observations for each factor, so maybe you are OK, but it's close.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to reconcile the two MSEs and F-statistics arithmetically using their respective DFs?

Comment: There isn't really anything to reconcile.